# Black lines around icon IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, icons, ios8

I am having this strange problem. I have added icons of sizes `120*120`, `58*58`, `80*80`. This is what I usually add as icon for all my iPhone apps. And there is no rounded corner in the design. But, when i run the app on iPhone4(IOS7), the icon shows a strange black line on all four edges(not on the rounded corners). I have cross checked the dimensions and confirmed it is all ok. I even tried migrating my app to asset catalogues, tried hard reseting the device but nothing helped. Then I tried running the same app on an iPad(running IOS8) and I found a similar issue, just that the lines now appear on two sides, not all. All other icons are ok. The problem just happens for this one app. Can anyone tell me what might be the probable issue and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The icons might have transparent edges. Remove the transparent edges.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a drop shadow attached to the icon which came along with the export. Sometimes designers add this drop shadow effect so you can better visualize the icon when designing, but if you add this to your app, you will get thin black lines around the app icon.